# Building C language STM32 project with existing Makefile under Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, svn, makefile, stm32

I am a newbie in Eclipse and STM32. So I would like to ask you for an advice with a problem which I have been solving. I have got a software for STM32. This software is written in C language and has an existing Makefile. The software is now placed on the SVN server. I need to build the project in Eclipse Neon 4.6.2 IDE running on Windows 7. I have installed the whole GNU ARM Toolchain according to tutorial [Mastering STM32](https://leanpub.com/mastering-stm32). Please can anybody direct me on any step by step instructions how to do that? Thanks in advance. [Sed utility warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpleL.jpg)

Comment: I have not read the book, but surely the book which advocates GCC / Eclipse / STM32 should explain how to do this? What stage exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I have two problems. The first one is building the project with existing Makefile. And the second one is how to create a new project (Makefile Project with Existing Code) in case I have the project placed on the svn server and I have to do Checkout. I haven't found any notes about these topics in the mentioned book. Do you have any ideas how how I can solve these problems?

Comment: You should be able to import an existing makefile project without any problems and then simply right click on the project and build it. With regard to project in SVN you should not have to create a new project. Simply check the project files into SVN with the code and when you check it out import an exisiting makefile project as before.  Have you installed the ARM C/C++ tools for eclipse?

Comment: Thank you for your advice Realtime Rik. I have followed your instructions and have received some warning message regarding the problems with the sed utility (please see the attachment in my question). This warning occurs despite the fact that I have installed the build tools from [github] (https://github.com/gnuarmeclipse/windows-build-tools/releases).

Comment: Sorry but I do not know anything about Sed or why it is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sed* is a unix utility. Maybe executed as a part of your makefile.

The error message is hidden by the second widnow. If it suggests, try to install it on your machine. I use GNU/Linux where it is essential part of the distribution. On Windows you can find a binary after some search.